# Trouble installing rgdal package on R 3.4 in Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: r, ubuntu

I have been working on GIS data for sometime now and I have been trying to install the rgdal package on my newly installed Ubuntu 17.04. I have preinstalled the gdal-bin, libroj-dev, libgdal-dev, libgdal1-dev packages but still it doesn't seem to work. I am using R 3.4 and I had some trouble while installing Rstudio as well. Any suggestions on this would be very helpful.

Edit: This is the error message I am getting while trying to install rgdal-

configure: error: gdal-config not found or not executable.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rgdal’

Comment: What is the error message when you tell us "it doesn't seem to work"?

Comment: I didn't have any problems with `rgal` with R 3.4 under Ubuntu 17.04. So you need to give us more info.

Comment: After installing when I try to load the package I am getting the following error message:

Error in library(rgdal) : there is no package called ‘rgdal’